# newrelic ignore multiple exceptions python

Tags: python, newrelic

Am using `newrelic-runprogram` with an `.ini` config to run my python program.

Am having problems with the `error_collector.ignore_errors` parameter in the `.ini` file.

I can specify one exception and it would skip that, for example

`error_collector.ignore_errors = celery.exceptions:Retry`

this works fine, it will suppress all the Retry exceptions. but if I need to suppress two exceptions, I used `;` and `,` but neither worked for me.

`error_collector.ignore_errors = celery.exceptions:Retry;celery.exceptions:MaxRetriesExceededError`

and

`error_collector.ignore_errors = celery.exceptions:Retry,celery.exceptions:MaxRetriesExceededError`

Can someone advise on how to multiple exception classes in newrelic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to let you know, this should be a space delimited configuration.

```
error_collector.ignore_errors = celery.exceptions:Retry celery.exceptions:MaxRetriesExceededError
```

You can find info on this [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-configuration#error-ignore).

Hope that helps!